# Manufacturers are narrowing seats. Any possibilities for price cut?

Tags: commercial-aviation, cost

> To squeeze more profits from each plane, the airline industry in the
>   last few years has begun to install extra rows of seats,  leading to a
>   crunch in legroom that has sparked tiffs and feuds among frustrated
>   passengers. ([Source](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-narrower-airline-seats-20150206-story.html))

.

> Airbus has suggested 3-5-3 configuration for A380, making airlines
>   have many extra seats.[Source](http://www.usatoday.com/story/todayinthesky/2015/04/16/airbus-pitches-adding-an-extra-seat-to-every-row-in-its-a380s/25867611/)

A similar plan is there for the B777. Is it likely that airlines will pass on some of greater earnings to their passengers, in return of the lack of comfort?

Comment: Passing savings back to the customer? Hahahahaha ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Airline Policy based question regarding the financial strategies and ambitions of carriers, and hence this question is not about aviation in general.

Comment: It could be theorized that it's the already low prices that is 'forcing' the airlines to stuff more in each flight...

Comment: You'll probably get a better response if you ask this question on [travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely not see a price cut, but you also might not see a price increase.

Seat pricing (along with just about any other service in a competitive market) is a complex function of actual cost to the company + desired profit + market factor. The last one is the difference between what they want to get and what the market is willing to pay. It is sometimes negative.